# Least squares estimator for parameter p in binomial distribution

Tags: probability, maximum-likelihood, inference, least-squares, binomial-distribution

I am trying to find the least square estimator for the parameter $p$ in $Bin(n,p)$ but is it even possible? Isn't it the same as finding it using MLE?

Comment: LS estimator is useful when your data can be expressed as a signal + noise, which is not the case here. Method of Moments estimators, MLE estimator, ..., can be applied.

Comment: LS and MLE is only the same for a normal distribution and maybe a few others ... https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/173621/linear-regression-any-non-normal-distribution-giving-identity-of-ols-and-mle

Comment: See also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/326350/what-is-happening-here-when-i-use-squared-loss-in-logistic-regression-setting

Answer (score 2):

As has been pointed out in comments, least squares and maximum likelihood don't always coincide.  However, for a Binomial distribution, they do.  We have the least squares problem:

$$\min_{\hat{p}} \sum_{i=1}^N(x_i - \hat{p})^2$$

Taking the derivative with respect to $\hat{p}$ and setting it equal to zero leads to:

$$\begin{eqnarray}
0 &=& 2\sum x_i - 2N\hat{p} \\
\hat{p} &=& {1\over N}\sum x_i
\end{eqnarray}$$

and checking the second derivative indicates that this is a minimum.  We didn't actually have to do the math, as it is well-known that the sample mean minimizes squared error, but for expository purposes there it is.

The maximum likelihood estimator:

$$\max_{\hat{p}} \hat{p}^{\sum x_i}(1-\hat{p})^{N-\sum x_i}$$

Working with logs is easier:

$$\max_{\hat{p}} \sum x_i\log \hat{p} +(N-\sum x_i)\log (1-\hat{p})$$

Taking the derivative leads to:

$$\begin{eqnarray} 0 &=& \sum x_i / \hat{p} - (N-\sum x_i)/(1-\hat{p})\\
0 &=& (1-\hat{p})\sum x_i - (N - \sum x_i) \hat{p} \\
0 &=& \sum x_i - \hat{p}\sum x_i - N\hat{p} + \hat{p}\sum x_i \\
N\hat{p} &=& \sum x_i \\
\hat{p} &=& {1 \over N} \sum x_i
\end{eqnarray}$$