# Cauchy MLE Reliability of Asymptotic Results

Tags: regression, bootstrap, median, likelihood, cauchy-distribution

I have the following regression model
$$
p_i = x'_i\beta +s \varepsilon_i
$$
with sample size $n \approx 150$ and 4 independent variables.

I have reason to believe and $\varepsilon_i$ is distributed iid standard cauchy. So I interpret the above regression as a sort of median regression and solve for $\beta$ and $s$ via maximizing the following log likelihood

$$
\hat\ell(\beta,s\mid x_1,\dotsc,x_n)=- n \log (s \pi) - \sum_{i=1}^n \log \left(1 + \left(\frac{p_i - x'_i\beta}{s}\right)^2\right)
$$

The first order conditions are
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{p_i - x'_i\beta}{s^2 + [p_i - x'_i\beta]^2} = 0
$$
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{s^2}{s^2 + [p_i - x'_i\beta]^2} - \frac{n}{2} = 0
$$

I am fine with numerical optimization (in R using optim or something).  But I have a few concerns

1. I know I am not guaranteed a unique solution in general..at least after seeing [MLE of the location parameter in a Cauchy distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/98971/mle-of-a-cauchy-distribution), but how should I go about verifying that my output is actually the global max? I have already run my model in R, and tried random start values which always yeild answers that are identical or very close.  I suppose I could also use start values from a preliminary OLS or non-parametric median regression?
2. Even if I find the global max and the cauchy specification is correct, can I be guaranteed the asymptotic standard errors are good approximations for the finite sample of 150?  I get very significant results for this model.  I bootstrapped the above and found much larger standard errors which makes everything insignificant :(.   But even then my sample size is only 150 and I am bootstrapping Cauchy distributed data, so the bootstrap may not be so reliable either?
3. I suppose the industry standard alternative is the standard non-parametric median regression with bootstrapped standard errors i.e.

$$
\underset{\beta}{arg min}  \left[-\sum_{p_{i}<x'_i\beta}(p_{i}-x'_i\beta)+\sum_{p_{i}\geq x'_i\beta}(p_{i}-x'_i\beta) \right]
$$

Would this be a better idea even if I am confident about my Cauchy assumption? Again, I only have 150 obs.

Long story short.  I like the Cauchy for theoretical reasons and because it gives me significant coefficients.  On the other hand, I am concerned because the non-parametric bootstrap gives higher standard errors implying insignificance.  I also don't know how well I can trust the local maxima to be global during numeric optimization.  Thank you for all your help.

Comment: I wouldn't use OLS values as starting points; they might work well some of the time but you're risking ending up in a local optimum far from one you'd like to be in. You want a robust regression procedure. If x's may be outlying as well, you'll also want something robust to influential outliers for  starting values.

Comment: @Glen_b I could use a quantile regression (for the 50th quantile) to estimate the start values of the $\beta$ at least...is that a better idea?  I am also considering just going with the quantile regression instead of the Cauchy.  However, based on the bootstrapping I have already done, I doubt my estimates will be significant. I suppose it's worth the shot though. I also prefer the Cauchy for theoretical reasons.  But if the model is just too fragile, I would be fine switching over to a non-parametric method and accepting insignificant coefficients.

Comment: Certainly $L_1$ regression (i.e. 0.50 quantile) would better than OLS for starting points. However, it isn't robust to influential points (that may not be a concern in your application, I don't know). For the regression itself you might consider some other redescending M-estimator in robust regression in place of likelihood for the Cauchy perhaps, or possibly regression with t-errors (of which Cauchy is a special case) - $t_5$ seems a popular choice in some applications.