# Maximum likelihood estimator of location parameter of Cauchy distribution

Tags: self-study, maximum-likelihood, cauchy-distribution

I have reached up to

$$\frac{d\ln L}{d\mu}=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{2(x_i-u)}{1+(x_i-u)^2}$$

Where $u$ is location parameter.
And $L$ is likelihood function.
I'm not getting how to proceed. Please help.

Comment: Have you looked here? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution#Estimation_of_parameters

Comment: You can not solve this directly, You can use Newton-Raphson to get mle.

Comment: @DeepNorth exactly! But I'm not getting how to get the mle using Newton Raphson method. Please explain.

Comment: @Bey Yes, I've read it. But still in not able to guess what they are saying exactly.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ok, Let us say the pdf for the cauchy is :

$f(x;\theta)=\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{1}{1+(x-\theta)^2}$  here $\theta$ is median, not mean since for Cauchy mean is undefined.

$$L(\theta;x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{1}{1+(x_1-\theta)^2}\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{1}{1+(x_2-\theta)^2}\cdots\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{1}{1+(x_n-\theta)^2}\\=\frac{1}{\pi^n} \frac{1}{\prod[1+(x_i-\theta)^2]}$$

$$\ell(\theta;x)=-n\log\pi-\sum_{i=1}^n\log[1+(x_i-\theta)^2]$$

$$\frac{d\ell(\theta;x)}{d\theta}=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{2(x_i-\theta)}{1+(x_i-\theta)^2}$$

**This is exactly what you got, except here $\theta$ is median, not mean. I suppose $u$ is median in your formula.**

Next step, in order to find mle we need set $\frac{d\ell(\theta;x)}{d\theta} = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{2(x_i-\theta)}{1+(x_i-\theta)^2}=0$

Now $\theta$ is your variable, and $x_is$ are known values, you need to solve equation $\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{2(x_i-\theta)}{1+(x_i-\theta)^2}=0$

i.e. to solve $\frac{2(x_1-\theta)}{1+(x_1-\theta)^2}+\frac{2(x_2-\theta)}{1+(x_2-\theta)^2}+\cdots+\frac{2(x_n-\theta)}{1+(x_n-\theta)^2}=0$. It seems to solve this equation will be very difficult. Therefore, we need Newton-Raphson method.

I think a lot of calculus books talk about the method

The formula for Newton-Raphson method can be written as $$\hat{\theta^1}=\hat{\theta^0}-\frac{\ell'(\hat{\theta^0})}{\ell''(\hat{\theta^0})} \tag 1$$

$\hat{\theta^0}$ is your initial guess of $\theta$

$\ell'$ is the first derivative of log likelihood function.

$\ell''$ is the second derivative of log likelihood function.

From $\hat{\theta^0}$ you can get $\hat{\theta^1}$ then you put $\hat{\theta^1}$ to $(1)$ then you get $\hat{\theta^2}$ and put it to $(1)$ to get $\hat{\theta^3}$...continue this iterations until to there are no big changes between $\hat{\theta^n}$ and $\hat{\theta^{n-1}}$

The followings are R function I wrote to get mle for the Cauchy distribution.

```
mlecauchy=function(x,toler=.001){      #x is a vector here
startvalue=median(x)
n=length(x);
thetahatcurr=startvalue;
# Compute first deriviative of log likelihood
firstderivll=2*sum((x-thetahatcurr)/(1+(x-thetahatcurr)^2))
# Continue Newton’s method until the first derivative
# of the likelihood is within toler of 0.001
while(abs(firstderivll)>toler){
# Compute second derivative of log likelihood
 secondderivll=2*sum(((x-thetahatcurr)^2-1)/(1+(x-thetahatcurr)^2)^2);
# Newton’s method update of estimate of theta
thetahatnew=thetahatcurr-firstderivll/secondderivll;
thetahatcurr=thetahatnew;
# Compute first derivative of log likelihood
firstderivll=2*sum((x-thetahatcurr)/(1+(x-thetahatcurr)^2))
}
list(thetahat=thetahatcurr);
}
```

Now suppose your data are $x_1=1.94,x_2=0.59,x_3=-5.98,x_4=-0.08,x_5-0.77$

```
x<-c(-1.94,0.59,-5.98,-0.08,-0.77)
mlecauchy(x,0.0001)
```

Result:

```
#$thetahat
#[1] -0.5343968
```

We also can use R build in function to get mle.

```
optimize(function(theta) -sum(dcauchy(x, location=theta, log=TRUE)),  c(-100,100)) 

#we use negative sign here
```

Results:

```
#$minimum
#[1] -0.5343902
```

The result is almost the same as home-made codes.

---

**Ok, as you required, let us do this by hand.**

First we get an initial guess will be median of  data $-5.98, -1.94, -0.77, -0.08,  0.59 $

The median is $-0.77$

Next we already know that $l'(\theta)=\frac{dl(\theta;x)}{d\theta}=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{2(x_i-\theta)}{1+(x_i-\theta)^2}$

and $$l''(\theta)=\frac{dl^2(\theta;x)}{d(\theta}=\frac{d(\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{2(x_i-\theta)}{1+(x_i-\theta)^2})}{d\theta}=2\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{(x_i-\theta)^2-1}{[1+(x_i-\theta)^2]^2}$$

Now we plug in the $\hat{\theta^0}$ i.e median to $l'(\theta)$ and $l''(\theta)$

i.e. replace $\theta$ with $\hat{\theta^0}$ i.e median i.e $-0.77$

\begin{align}
\ell'(\theta) = {} & \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{2(x_i-\theta)}{1+(x_i-\theta)^2} \\[10pt]
= {} &\frac{2[-5.98-(-0.77)]}{1+[(-5.98-(-0.77)^2]} + \frac{2[-1.94-(-0.77)]}{1+[(-1.94-(-0.77)^2]} + \frac{2[-0.77-(-0.77)]}{1+[(-0.77-(-0.77)^2]}  \\[6pt]
& {} +\frac{2[-0.08-(-0.77)]}{1+[(-0.08-(-0.77)^2]} +\frac{2[0.59-(-0.77)]}{1+[(0.59-(-0.77)^2]}\\[10pt]
= {} & \text{??}
\end{align}

Next plug in $x_1$ to $x_5$ and $-0.77$ to get $\ell''(\theta)$ then you can get $\hat{\theta^1}$

Ok, I have to stop here, it is too troublesome to calculate these values by hand.

Comment: Your answer is right. I did the same way. But we can go this way only if we know the values in the sample. Does That mean there's no compact or generalized form for the MLE of location parameter of Cauchy distribution?

Comment: I think generalized form for the MLE will be very complicated. I don't know if there is one.

Comment: Check this out.. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/98971/mle-of-the-location-parameter-in-a-cauchy-distribution/98978?noredirect=1#comment317958_98978 There's a generalized form for it. But they have done some centering if Cauchy distribution, I don't know how! They've assumed the sample of size 2. I ain't getting why! Please help.

Comment: They assumed $x_1=x; x_2=-x$ and they only got this two data points $x$  and $-x$, I think that is a very special case not a generalized form.

Comment: Umm.. I still have some doubts. 1. What will be the initial guess for the theta hat? Will it be the median value from given sample? 2. l' and l" are derivatives with respect to theta or x?

Comment: Umm.. I still have some doubts. 1. What will be the initial guess for the theta hat? Will it be the median value from given sample? 2. l' and l" are derivatives with respect to theta or x?

Comment: Median is the initial guess. $L'$ and $L''$ are derivatives with respect to $\theta$

Comment: Ohkay. I'm trying to solve it manually. What will be the initial guess in example you mentioned? Is it -0.08?

Comment: For this data, -5.98, -1.94, -0.77, -0.08 , 0.59 median is -0.77. Not need to solve it manually.

Comment: I'm getting this equation after putting the median value (-0.77). So now I should go solving by putting values given in the sample. Like first putting x1 and then we will obtain thetahat1 then solving the same equation putting value of thetahat1 and x2 to obtain thetahat2? Is it what you meant?

Comment: I typed in answer box by mistake. Please check it.

Comment: I'm getting an equation after putting the median value (-0.77).

So now I should go solving by putting values given in the sample. Like first putting x1 and then we will obtain thetahat1 then solving the same equation putting value of thetahat1 and x2 to obtain thetahat2? Is it what you meant?

Comment: yes, but I don't know how many iterations you need to get to the convergence. You can check it by modifying the program. You had better not do it by hand.

Comment: Yeah. But I've given that assignment to solve it manually. I did the same way you told. But by each iteration thetahat keeps increasing. And thetahat is coming out to be greater than all the sample values. Much greater.

Comment: Hey, please solve my doubts.

Comment: In the case of the Cauchy location (among many other MLE problems) this approach will find *a turning point* of the likelihood. But the Cauchy likelihood is in general multimodal... in general there's no guarantee you found the right peak (the one with the highest likelihood).