# Maximum likelihood estimator of Cauchy distribution but with a catch

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood, cauchy-distribution

I have an exercise to solve that states that we need to find the **Maximum likelihood estimator of location parameter of the Cauchy distribution given a set X={x1,x2} , |x1-x2|<2**

Now I worked using this approach: [Maximum likelihood estimator of location parameter of Cauchy distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/174117/maximum-likelihood-estimator-of-location-parameter-of-cauchy-distribution?noredirect=1&lq=1&newreg=9333ec570f664a9fb24c37105539164b)

but I can't get to grasp how " **given a set X={x1,x2} , |x1-x2|<2**" changes the problem.

Thank you

Comment: The meaning isn't at all clear.  Are you quoting the exercise *exactly* and *in its entirety?*

Comment: The exercise isn't in English so I translated but it, but yeah that's all it says, it also gives the formula of the cauchy distribution that is also in the other link. The extra part says: "find the MLE based on a data set of X = {x1,x2}, |x1-x2| <2

Comment: It is crucially important to explain that the $x_i$ are the dataset.  There still remain several different ways to interpret the constraint $|x_1-x_2|\lt 2.$

Comment: I wish i understood but that's all it says... I think what it really means is that the sum doens't go from 1 to infinity but it only goes from 1 to 2, hence the X= {x1,x2}. This way it can be solved for normally when calculating the derivative = 0 without using the Newton-Raphson method.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you have only two samples $x_1,x_2$ then the likelihood is maximized by finding the maximum of

$$\mathcal{L}(\lambda ; x_1,x_2) \propto\frac{1}{(\gamma^{2}+(x_1-\lambda)^2)}\frac{1}{(\gamma^{2}+(x_2-\lambda)^2)}$$

Which is equivalent to finding the minimum of the polynomial

$$(\gamma^{2}+(x_1-\lambda)^2)(\gamma^{2}+(x_2-\lambda)^2))$$

We can rephrase this in terms of $\bar{x} = \frac{x_1+x_2}{2}$ and $d= \frac{x_1-x_2}{2}$

$$(\gamma^{2}+(\bar{x}-d-\lambda)^2)(\gamma^{2}+(\bar{x}+d-\lambda)^2)$$

without loss of generality we can set $\bar{x}=0$ (it will just shift the solution if $\bar{x}\neq0$)

$$(\gamma^{2}+(d-\lambda)^2)(\gamma^{2}+(d-\lambda)^2) =
\gamma^4 + 2 \gamma^2 (d^2+\lambda^2) + (d^2+\lambda^2)^2 - 4 d^2\lambda^2$$

Whose derivative to $\lambda$ is equal to $0$ in the minimum

$$4(\gamma^2 - d^2+\lambda^2) \lambda = 0$$

In the case of $d^2 < \gamma^2$ then this is equal to zero in only a single point $\lambda = 0$ (or in the general case in $\lambda = \bar{x}$).

Your problem probably uses $\gamma = 1$ such that we have as condition $|d| < 1$ or equivalent $|x_1-x_2| < 2$. For this condition the likelihood is minimised in $\lambda = \frac{x_1+x_2}{2}$. For other cases you have multiple minima.

> but I can't get to grasp how " **given a set X={x1,x2} , |x1-x2|<2**" changes the problem.

**So what changes with the condition $|x_1-x_2| < 2$ is that the likelihood function has a single minimum.**

Comment: Why doesn't $x_2$ appear in your expression?  Why does $\lambda$ appear on both sides?  How does this interpret and handle the condition in the question?

Comment: @whuber I am doing this answer on my phone and had to create a 'safe' of my partial answer. Re-typing equations is annoying.

Comment: Very nice interpretation and solution! +1.

Comment: @Sextus  Great approach! What I thought might be possible in order to get to a solution with my stupid mind  is:  when you take the general approach of using the ln of the function and calculating its derivative such as you do for any MLE problem and get a sum of 1 to n, to take the sum of 1 to 2 since you have 2 Xs(x1,x2) and find for what θ it is equal to a zero. Do you think this would still be a valid solution?

Comment: @GiannhsMeh if you maximize the logarithm of the likelihood function then you should arrive at the same situation, except with some different algebraic steps. $$\frac{d\ln L}{d\mu}=\frac{2(x_1-u)}{1+(x_1-u)^2}+\frac{2(x_2-u)}{1+(x_2-u)^2} = 0$$

After getting the denominators equal, you get the same situation as in my answer.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus That's great, thank you so much

Comment: actually I am not so sure, you would have to work it out. But you can use the same trick of converting to $x_1 = \bar{x} + d$ and $x_2 = \bar{x} - d$ and setting $\bar{x} =  0$. Or alternatively you can set $x_1 = 0$

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus Yeah the math is a pain in the ass to work with in this one but I guess your approach is way more elegant!

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus Sorry but I just noticed that the cauchy distribution has an 1/π  term multiplied by the L function you inputed at least in my problem. Does this modify the solution in any way?

Comment: @GiannhsMeh the likelihood function is independent of multiplicative constants. I eliminated it from the likelihood function and used the symbol $\propto$ to indicate that the relationship is a proportionality relationship.

Comment: how would you explain this constraint $|x_1-x_2|<2$ intuitively?

Comment: @aksakal For $|x_1-x_2|>2$ you get that the location parameter is more likely nearby either $x_1$ or $x_2$ than in the middle. This happens when the change of the loglikelihood is larger for moving towards the parameter than for moving away from the parameter.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus why do you think it's intuitive?

Comment: @Aksakal It is in this shape https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=log%281%2F%281%2Bx%5E2%29%29 and the sum of two of those https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=log%281%2F%281%2Bx%5E2%29%29+%2B+log%281%2F%281%2B%28x-3%29%5E2%29%29

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus, I'd call this a *spontaneous symmetry breaking*: when the distance between the points is large enough it's more likely that the center is not between the points, and it must happen to heavy tailed shapes

Comment: If the log-likelihood function f(x) has a peak in x=0, but if it would be concave then it would not have been possible for a sum f(x)+(x+a) to have a global maximum different from a/2. The loglikelihood function of the Cauchy distribution is not concave.

Answer (score 1):

From symmetry principle location can only be $\frac{x_1+x_2} 2$, when there is a unique solution.

this is regardless of the estimation approach. For instance, a particular estimator, such as MLE, may not even exist in every case. However, if it does exist and it is unique, then the symmetry dictates what should it be.

### non MLE estimation

If we don't constrain ourselves with MLE, then we could get the parameters differently. Obviously, the peak (center) is still the same half-way between $x_1$ and $x_2$. So, we only need to figure the other parameter.

In physics we used to characterize Breit-Wigner function with half-width at half-height parameter, which is equal to a shape parameter $\gamma$ of Cauchy distribution [definition in statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution): PDF reaches its half height when you step left or right by half-width from the peak. So, naturally, the "width" is $2\gamma$ and intuitively it should be estimated as $2\hat\gamma=|x_1-x_2|$.

The "height" of PDF is at its peak $x_0$:$$H=\frac 1 {\pi\gamma}$$ Solve the PDF for $x$ to equal $H/2$: $$\frac H 2=\frac 1 {2\pi\gamma}=\frac 1 {\pi\gamma\left[1+\left(\frac{x-x_0} \gamma\right)^2\right]}$$ to get $$\frac{x-x_0}\gamma=1$$ So when the variable is $x_0\pm\gamma$ the PDF reaches its half-height

Comment: @Aksakal, that's right for *an* estimate. But it is not a right argument for the maximum likelihood estimator. The maximum likelihood estimator does not exist for $|x_1-x_2|>2$, so the symmetry principle should state that the estimator can only be $\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}$ *if* the estimator exists.

Comment: Symmetry directly implies only that $(x_1+x_2)/2$ is a critical point of the likelihood: more is needed to demonstrate it is a global minimum (or even a local minimum).

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus, agreed, updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

To come up with an expression for the conditional likelihood, you express the joint likelihood $L(x_1, x_2)$ as $L(x_2|x_1)L(x_1)$. The unconstrained $x_1$ can be anything of course, so has the usual likelihood

$$f(x_1) = \frac{1}{\pi (1+(x_1-\mu)^2)}$$.

The *conditional* $x_2$ density can be expressed by assigning likelihood 0 to any value more than 2 units beyond $x_1$, then the density can be "normalized" by the density area within the 2 units, i.e.

$$ f(x_2|x_1) =  \dfrac{f(x_2)}{F(x_1+2) - F(x_1 - 2)} \times \mathcal{I}(|x_1-x_2|<2)$$

I am not sure if the expression $L(x_1, x_2) = f(x_2|x_1) f(x_1)$ has an analytic solution or if it's really necessary to obtain one. But numeric solvers should give you a solution here, and some simulations should show you if the estimator has any nice asymptotic properties.

Comment: I cannot make sense of this, because your notation doesn't treat $\mu$ as the variable, while that is *essential* for MLE.