# Why is Max Likelihood Estimation NP-Hard in General

Tags: machine-learning, normal-distribution, maximum-likelihood, expectation-maximization, np

I am watching the lecture [here](https://youtu.be/0WX0h5fu0zs?t=188) and the author says that in the machine learning setting where data is assumed to be generated by a model with a few parameters:

**Max Likelihood parameters are NP hard to find in general (non convex objective).**

And in practice heuristics such as EM are used.

I guess everywhere these things are stated as a metter of fact but explanations are missing.

Could you explain how can a model have an intractable max likelihood? How to prove it. I have seem problems such as SAT proven NP hard, but in this context I do not have an intuition of how to approach. Do we need first to show non-convexity before proving NP hard?

Comment: I do not understand the logic of your question: a single counterexample will not shed any light on an assertion that is said to hold "in general."

Comment: @whuber yes, but i will get an intuition about how to move ahead to prove in different situations. That will be very helpful while trying to understand the papers. thx.

Comment: The model you name has an extremely simple likelihood whose maximum is easily found and has a closed form.  There doesn't seem to be much to learn from it about the situation you mention at the outset.

Comment: @whuber yes, univariate Gaussian is a bad example of what i wanted to ask. i will edit the question. thx.

Comment: See [MLE of the location parameter in a Cauchy distribution](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/98971/17230) for a simple example of a non-convex objective.